# Windows 10 PC cannot list SQL Server instances

Tags: sql-server, windows-10

Out of multiple Windows workstation, only a few running Windows 10 Pro can't list existing SQL instances over the local area network, while others can. 
DNS and default gateway are the same on all machines.

So far I have attempted to:

- disable client firewall
- list servers [through UDL shortcut](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/farukcelik/2007/12/31/basics-first-udl-test/)
- run Powershell command `[System.Data.Sql.SqlDataSourceEnumerator]::Instance.GetDataSources()`

Why these PC won't list any existing server?

Comment: Does this help --> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/browse-for-servers-network-servers?view=sql-server-2014

Comment: Thanks Ross, but the instances are visible from other machines